# Unable to start mysql docker client on Mac M1

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker-compose configuration as follows:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_HOST_MYSQL_PORT:-3306}:3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - ./storage/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
```

then I ran the following: `docker-compose up mysql`

I'm getting the following error:

```
[+] Running 5/5
 ⠿ mysql Pulled                                                                                                                                   14.1s
   ⠿ 517a40cb4717 Pull complete                                                                                                                    5.9s
   ⠿ 4a26b26e2152 Pull complete                                                                                                                   10.0s
   ⠿ 14794e2450ed Pull complete                                                                                                                   10.0s
   ⠿ 754b01a0f0ff Pull complete                                                                                                                   10.0s
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container client-app-mysql-1  Recreated                                                                                                         0.4s
Attaching to client-app-mysql-1
client-app-mysql-1  | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.23-1.1.19
client-app-mysql-1  | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.23-1.1.19
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:12.591047Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 26
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:12.597713Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:12.611927Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:12.612425Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:13.343343Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012224] [InnoDB] Tablespace flags are invalid in datafile: ./ibdata1, Space ID:0, Flags: 21. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:13.344157Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012237] [InnoDB] Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile './ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:13.344888Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption.
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:13.833188Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:13.835836Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:13.837260Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
client-app-mysql-1  | 2022-03-29T08:41:13.838870Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
client-app-mysql-1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same problem once moved to a M1 machine.
Didn't dig much into the issue, but got it working by attaching a docker volume and in this way the DB data are persistent

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  dcm-mysql:
    hostname: dcm-mysql
    container_name: dcm-mysql
    image: mysql:8.0.29-oracle
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dcm
      MYSQL_USER: dcm
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dcm
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      # - ../local_data/mdb/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - dcm-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mariadb
volumes:
  dcm-mysql-data:
```