# MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD ignored by docker mariadb using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  with-docker-multi-env-staging:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/staging/Dockerfile
    image: with-docker-multi-env-staging
    ports:
      - '3002:3000'
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: dashboard
      MARIADB_DATABASE: dashboard
      MARIADB_USER: dashboard
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: dashboard
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

But when I login into the maria db Terminal I can only authenticate with `root:example` and not `root:dashboard`. (`example` is the default value which I want to replace)

[image]

[image]

In fact, authenticating with "dashboard:dashboard" doesn't work at all and this is how I found this initially. What am I doing wrong? This is my first day with docker and I am already frustrated. ;D

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem [by attaching a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72408746/9041632). Updated & working `docker-compose.yml` here:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  with-docker-multi-env-staging:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/staging/Dockerfile
    image: with-docker-multi-env-staging
    ports:
      - '3002:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dashboard
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dashboard
      MYSQL_USER: dashboard
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dashboard
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  db-data:
```

**Edit: Improved Version** based on comment by [danblack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10195153/danblack) by below.

*Improvements:*

- use `MARIADB_` instead of `MYSQL_`
- added health checks
- added an extra layer for database migrations (absolutely bonkers yo)

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  next-staging:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/staging/Dockerfile
    image: next-staging
    ports:
      - '3002:3000'
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      migrate-db:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  migrate-db:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/staging/migrate.Dockerfile
    image: migrate-db
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: dashboard
      MARIADB_DATABASE: dashboard
      MARIADB_USER: dashboard
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: dashboard
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: Note your original `MARIADB_*` [env](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server-docker-official-image-environment-variables/) names where correct. Also you can add a [`healthcheck`](https://github.com/MariaDB/SCARY/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L83)  and your build can depend on a [healthy service of `db`](https://github.com/MariaDB/SCARY/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L30-L32).

Comment: Updated my answer with your recommendations - thank you vm! Didn't know about healthcheck, but I am very happy with the solution now. Especially considering it's day 2 with Docker ;D

Comment: Nice use of migrations, and `service_completed_successfully`. That's a new one for me. Thank you.