# Docker flask not able to connect to docker mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, flask

I have a flask app running in a docker container. I am not able to connect to the mysql server, running on a different container.

I am getting this error in the logs

```
2023-07-12 16:39:58 2023-07-12 20:39:58,037:37  ERROR   database.database.      Problem connecting to the server. Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (111 Connection refused)
2023-07-12 16:39:58 2023-07-12 20:39:58,037:37  ERROR   database.database.      Problem connecting to the server. Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

This is my docker compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: db_container
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "6970:3306"
        networks:
          - network-backend
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secretpwd
        volumes:
          - db-data:/Users/local/path/in/my/system/
        expose:
          - 3306
          - 33060

    backend:
        image: image_backend
        container_name: backend_container
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "6969:6543"
        networks:
          - network-backend
        links:
          - db
networks:
    network-backend:

volumes:
  db-data: {}
```

Both the containers are running. MySQL server is running in the mysql container.
Using

```
docker network inspect network-backend
```

I see that both the containers are connected to it.

Also, I am able to connect to the server using mysql workbench, using localhost:6970 (the port exposed using the docker compose file)

I have read other answers, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d` a second time, does it start?  (Do you need to wait for the database to actually be ready?)  The `links:` option activates an obsolete Docker networking mode, does deleting it help at all?

Comment: On the 'wait until ready', `mariadb` could use a [healthcheck.sh](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-healthcheck-sh-script/) like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76665666/mariadb-root-password-ignored-by-docker-mariadb-using-docker-compose/76665956) so they are ordered. Notice of interest, I'm a MariaDB Foundation employee.

Comment: In general i would remove the `network` section and the `links` part from the compose file. Docker Compose will automatically create a network for the containers